How to save a PySpark dataframe to Apache Ignite with JDBC driver?
I have a PySpark application and I want to save some dataframe to Apache Ignite database (to a new table).
I have created a Spark session with Spark JDBC driver plugged and I'm trying to save a dataframe:
from datetime import datetime, date
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import Row

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(a=1, b=2., c='string1', d=date(2000, 1, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0)),
    Row(a=2, b=3., c='string2', d=date(2000, 2, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 2, 12, 0)),
    Row(a=4, b=5., c='string3', d=date(2000, 3, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 3, 12, 0))
])
df.write.option("driver", "org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver").option("primaryKeyFields", "a").jdbc(url="jdbc:ignite:thin://172.19.0.1:10800", table="foo_table", mode="overwrite")

And I'm getting the following error:
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2484.jdbc.
: java.sql.SQLException: No PRIMARY KEY defined for CREATE TABLE

Can it be fixed somehow?

This question is similar to: Persisting Spark DataFrame to Ignite. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Spark and PySpark are not the same.
